How can I mark a checkbox option from TreeSelect component with the selection of another option from the same dropdown?
everyone!
I'm using the TreeSelect component with checkboxes from PrimeReact 7.2.1. I want to implement the following behaviour: When I click on option Cost of Goods Sold to External Customer (see photo 1) the option bellow should be marked as well.

I will be very grateful, if you could give me some ideas.
I tried to implement the logic in the handler function, but didn't do nothing. I also tried other properties and handlers from this component, but there aren't helpful.
I can manipulate the labels from photo2 (for example: A001 and etc), but it's not possible with the marked options:

This is my TreeSelect component:

When I hard code a value in the value property, its marked, but can't do it when clicking on another option. I can also modify the values, which I pass, but nothing happens again.
